# how to create a custom mutex

Tags: c#, mutex

interview question :

create your own mutex :

my implementation :

> public static class MyMutex
>     {

```
    static Queue<Thread> queue = new Queue<Thread>();

    static int locked_state = 0 ;
    static int inner_proc = 0;

    public static void WaitOne()
    {
        // spin loop untill inner proccess are complete 
        while (Interlocked.Equals(inner_proc ,1))
        {}

        Interlocked.Exchange(ref inner_proc, 1);
        // if in a locked state queue current thread and set to inifinite sleep 
        if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref locked_state, 1) == 1)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(Thread.CurrentThread);
            Thread.Sleep(-1);
        }

        Interlocked.Exchange(ref inner_proc, 0);
    }
    public static void ReleaseMutex()
    {
        // spin loop untill inner proccess are complete 
        while (Interlocked.Equals(inner_proc ,1))
        {}
        // lock inner process (change to queue)            
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref inner_proc, 1);

        if( queue.Count > 0 )
        {
            Thread t = queue.Dequeue();
            t.Start();                 
        }
        if (queue.Count == 0)
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref locked_state, 0);
        }
        // end lock inner process ( change to queue )            
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref inner_proc, 0);
    }
}
```

explained :

if the mutex is in a locked state the thread is queued and then the thread  goes into sleep mode for an infinite timespan .
the check and assignment are made atomically  so that the first thread going in will "lock"
the state (with a 1 flag ) before any other's get a chance .

the problem is when de-queuing a thread another can come in and call waitOne() before the locked_state could be flaged as 0 ; 
for that reason i have an inner spin-loop which blocks 2 threads to simultaneously alter the queue .

*another  problem is how can i put a thread to sleep and wake it up with out like i attempt 
on doing here ( but i cannot use thread.Start() like i did it throws an exception )
and thread suspend and resume have been deprecated .

so in general (i don't really know how to implement a mutex) 
any hints , ideas or helpful links on how to accomplish this would be most appreciated .

Comment: How to reinvent the wheel is a poor interview question.

Comment: What guidlines did they give you?  Can you use thread locks, or does it have to be "pure" (whatever that means in managed code)?  If you can use thread locks, you could at least avoid multi-thread issues that way... not sure if that is cheating ;)

Comment: Making the methods `static` isn't going to help you here.

Comment: i can't use locks , that would be cheating

Comment: @Jeff yes i know i had something else in mind before 
but it doesn't hurt me here ether so i left it this 
way .

Comment: @subt13 asking the interviewee to demonstrate their understanding of a concept is a good interview question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer at least part of your question, here is how I would handle pausing/resuming a thread:

```
// In the thread to be suspended:
// This will return false if the thread needs to end immediately.
// This will return true if normal operation should continue.
private bool SuspendCurrentThread()
{
    try
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }
    catch (ThreadInterruptedException)
    {
        // Resume normal operation.
        return true;
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// ...
// ... 
// ...

// In the thread that is to trigger the resume:
private Thread OtherThread = /* something */;

private void ResumeOtherThread()
{
    OtherThread.Interrupt();
}

private void KillOtherThread()
{
    OtherThread.Abort(); // Fire a ThreadAbortException in the other thread if it is in a waiting state.
    OtherThread.Join(); // Wait until the other thread has exited before continuing.
}
```